WebDriverError: session not created: 'DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist' since upgrade from chrome v127 to v128 (or higher) in docker environment
I'm trying to run webdriver.io tests in a docker container against a recent chrome version.
When using a docker image with chrome 127, my tests run fine. After upgrading chrome to v128 or later, I get WebDriverError: session not created
My Webdriver.io capability configuration:
capabilities: [{
    'wdio:maxInstances': 1,
    'wdio:enforceWebDriverClassic': true,  
    browserName: 'chrome',
    acceptInsecureCerts: true,
    'goog:chromeOptions': {
        args: [
            '--headless',
            '--no-sandbox',
            '--disable-gpu',
            '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
            '--disable-infobars',
            '--disable-search-engine-choice-screen',
            '--window-size=1920,1200']
    }
  }]

My Dockerfile:
FROM node:22

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install sudo \
    && apt-get install -y unzip \
    # See https://crbug.com/795759
    && apt-get install -yq libgconf-2-4 \
    && apt-get install gnupg -y \
    && apt-get install -y wget --no-install-recommends \
    && apt-get install iputils-ping -y \
    && apt-get install libpci-dev -y \
    && wget --quiet --output-document=- https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | gpg --dearmor > /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/google-archive.gpg \
    && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'


RUN  apt-get update \
     && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable --no-install-recommends \
     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN echo "node    ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/node

Output from wdio:
...
16:12:35 [0-0] 2024-11-06T15:12:35.177Z INFO @wdio/utils: Started Chromedriver v130.0.6723.116 with params --port=43274 --allowed-origins=* --allowed-ips=0.0.0.0 in 105ms on port 43274
16:12:35 [0-0] 2024-11-06T15:12:35.182Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://localhost:43274/session
16:12:35 [0-0] 2024-11-06T15:12:35.182Z INFO webdriver: DATA {
16:12:35 [0-0]   capabilities: {
16:12:35 [0-0]     alwaysMatch: {
16:12:35 [0-0]       'wdio:maxInstances': 1,
16:12:35 [0-0]       'wdio:enforceWebDriverClassic': true,
16:12:35 [0-0]       browserName: 'chrome',
16:12:35 [0-0]       acceptInsecureCerts: true,
16:12:35 [0-0]       'goog:chromeOptions': [Object]
16:12:35 [0-0]     },
16:12:35 [0-0]     firstMatch: [ {} ]
16:12:35 [0-0]   }
16:12:35 [0-0] }
16:12:35 [0-0] 2024-11-06T15:12:35.356Z DEBUG webdriver: request failed due to response error: session not created
16:12:35 [0-0] 2024-11-06T15:12:35.357Z WARN webdriver: WebDriverError: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
16:12:35 [0-0]   (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
16:12:35 [0-0]   (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.) when running "http://localhost:43274/session" with method "POST" and args "{"capabilities":{"alwaysMatch":{"wdio:maxInstances":1,"wdio:enforceWebDriverClassic":true,"browserName":"chrome","acceptInsecureCerts":true,"goog:chromeOptions":{"binary":"/usr/bin/google-chrome","args":["--headless","--no-sandbox","--disable-gpu","--disable-dev-shm-usage","--disable-infobars","--disable-search-engine-choice-screen","--window-size=1920,1200"]}},"firstMatch":[{}]}}"

Any ideas?
I tried to add '--remote-debugging-port=9222' chrome option, not getting the 'DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist' error anymore but the result is still the same: session cannot be created:
16:44:59 [0-2] 2024-11-06T15:44:59.757Z INFO chromedriver: ChromeDriver was started successfully on port 46617.
16:44:59 [0-2] 2024-11-06T15:44:59.758Z INFO @wdio/utils: Started Chromedriver v130.0.6723.116 with params --port=46617 --allowed-origins=* --allowed-ips=0.0.0.0 in 116ms on port 46617
16:44:59 [0-2] 2024-11-06T15:44:59.761Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://localhost:46617/session
16:44:59 [0-2] 2024-11-06T15:44:59.762Z INFO webdriver: DATA {
16:44:59 [0-2]   capabilities: {
16:44:59 [0-2]     alwaysMatch: {
16:44:59 [0-2]       'wdio:maxInstances': 1,
16:44:59 [0-2]       'wdio:enforceWebDriverClassic': true,
16:44:59 [0-2]       browserName: 'chrome',
16:44:59 [0-2]       acceptInsecureCerts: true,
16:44:59 [0-2]       'goog:chromeOptions': [Object]
16:44:59 [0-2]     },
16:44:59 [0-2]     firstMatch: [ {} ]
16:44:59 [0-2]   }
16:44:59 [0-2] }
16:45:00 [0-2] 2024-11-06T15:45:00.893Z DEBUG webdriver: request failed due to response error: session not created
16:45:00 [0-2] 2024-11-06T15:45:00.895Z WARN webdriver: WebDriverError: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
16:45:00 [0-2]   (chrome not reachable)
16:45:00 [0-2]   (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.) when running "http://localhost:46617/session" with method "POST" and args "{"capabilities":{"alwaysMatch":{"wdio:maxInstances":1,"wdio:enforceWebDriverClassic":true,"browserName":"chrome","acceptInsecureCerts":true,"goog:chromeOptions":{"binary":"/usr/bin/google-chrome","args":["--remote-debugging-port=9222","--headless","--no-sandbox"]}},"firstMatch":[{}]}}"

I also tried adding browserVersion to the capabilities so WebdriverIO will download and install the requested combination, regardless of whether there's an existing installation. I get the same error with browserVersion: '128'. With browserVersion: '127' I see no issues.

Found the problem: chrome probably stopped/didn't start due to permission issues
My docker was running from a jenkins job, by changing the user from 'node' to the jenkins user the problems disappeared.
